# What's a good Feature film microphone?

Tags: microphone

Can you get a good microphone for feature films for around $800 - $850? If so, which? (Should be good for action, normal indoors filming and normal outdoors filming.)

Comment: What does "good" mean here? Reliable? Established? Versatile? Durable?

Comment: One I can use to make a film as close as possible to a feature film.

Comment: Have you considered renting microphones instead? Microphones are like camera lenses - there isn't one magic mic that will do everything you want. You can find a lot of good information by googling, but eventually you are going to have to do some experiments of your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to shoot on location then get a shotgun mic with a boom. If you want to overdub the voice over in a studio, then get a large diaphragm condenser mic.